# Having issues trying to destructure array to new variables for assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, destructuring

I am working on a project and am encountering an obstacle on something rather small. I am trying to take an array that has a string and a nested array. Remove the string assigning it to a new variable and then destructure the nested array into two new variables. I seem to be having problems as there is an undefined placeholder and I can't seem to find a way to get around it. I think I must be messing something up simple, but I would appreciate it if you could help me understand my mistake.
Any help would be great.

Here is the code which I can't seem to get working.

```js
let operandArray = ['x', [1, 1]]
let temporaryArray = [];

const operator = operandArray.shift();

temporaryArray = operandArray[0];
console.log(temporaryArray);

let [operand1, operand2] = [...operandArray];
console.log(operandArray);
console.log(operand1, operand2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: My guess is you meant to destructure `temporaryArray`, not `operandArray`? As in `let [operand1, operand2] = temporaryArray;`

Comment: That also solves it as well I think. Sometimes I get code blind and miss simple stuff like this haha. I appreciate the answer Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this.

```js
const operandArray = ['x', [1, 1]]
const [str, [x, y]] = operandArray;
console.log(str, x, y);
```

You may wanna have a look at this [blog post](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) for a more detailed explanation of the desctructuring syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much. This helped me solve my problem. I need to learn more about destructuring so I don't mess this up in the future. Thanks again!